# Get JSON data from Firebase and save it in a folder in Ionic Project

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

I have a functional app wherein the Provider takes data from assets/data/data.json

I want to move data.json to firebase, and whenever a user logins/ refreshes, I want to update the data.json with the data from Firebase (the whole tree, its not very big). The reason being, that I want to use the same Provider code without any changes:

```
@Injectable()
export class ConferenceData {
  data: any;


  constructor(public http: Http, public user: UserData) { }

  load(): any {
    if (this.data) {
      return Observable.of(this.data);
    } 
    else {
       return this.http.get('listRef')
        .map(this.processData, this); 
  }
}

  processData(data: any) {
    this.data = data.json();

    this.data.tracks = [];

    this.data.schedule.forEach((day: any) => {

      day.groups.forEach((group: any) => {

        group.sessions.forEach((session: any) => {
          session.speakers = [];
          if (session.speakerNames) {
            session.speakerNames.forEach((speakerName: any) => {
              let speaker = this.data.speakers.find((s: any) => s.name === speakerName);
              if (speaker) {
                session.speakers.push(speaker);
                speaker.sessions = speaker.sessions || [];
                speaker.sessions.push(session);
              }
            });
          }

          if (session.tracks) {
            session.tracks.forEach((track: any) => {
              if (this.data.tracks.indexOf(track) < 0) {
                this.data.tracks.push(track);
              }
            });
          }
        });
      });
    });

    return this.data;
  }
```

and basically keep everything else the same (except for importing Firebase libraries, and updating data.json).

Any way of doing that?

Comment: ? So you want to get a file from a server and update a local file with this retrieved file on refresh and login? Well is your `load()` called on refresh/login? Where do you want this code to be and what have you tried?

Comment: Use file plugin and use createFile method https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/

Comment: For saving JSON-like data I usually use https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/. Very light, fast and easy to use without having to deal with files (which CAN be difficult dealing with different OS). You can store your data per key or just save the whole JSON Object like `storage.set('my_json', my_json)`. Hope this is what youre looking for

Comment: @Frede I looked up on the link, but will it help in saving the whole JSON file, as is?

Comment: @PareshGami I was looking at https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file-downloader . I'm assuming what you've suggested is something similar? And do we need to test it on a real device only?

Comment: @Ivaro18 Yes, Right now I'm doing it onLoad; I've tried this: 
fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
 
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.download();
  }
  download() {
    console.log("Inside!");
    const url = 'https://_project-name_.firebaseio.com/';
    this.fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory + 'file.json').then((entry) => {
      console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
    }, () => {
      console.log("Error");
      // handle error
    });
  }